# Is it possible to create SSL certificate for local Subdomain?

Tags: networking, server, dns, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I host some services at home myself and so far have only used DNS records and self-signed certificates for them.  Now I'm having some issues with self-signed certificates (some apps are not working properly) and am trying to get a public domain to fix these issues.  Before I do that, I just want to clear up one question that I have.

If I had my own public domain, let's say example.com and created a local subdomain, let's say plex.example.com.  Can I create a Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate for this local subdomain?  or should the subdomain also be public?

Comment: Letsencrypt checks that you own the domain. If it cannot see it, the check won't work. Either the subdomain has to be public or the other way is with a wildcard cert (*.example.com) which would cover all subdomains. See https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578

Comment: @dratenik Your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you can use wildcard certificate for subdomains. For example, you can obtain certificate for `*.example.com` and use it for all your subdomains.

However, you cannot obtain non-wildcard certificate for a local network. See the [guidance](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.7.0-1.pdf) from CA browser forum:

> 4.2.2.Approval or Rejection of Certificate Applications
>
> CAs SHALL NOT issue certificates containing Internal Names (see
> section 7.1.4.2.1).